# How do you indicate the "length" of instalments?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases

I'm wondering whether it's correct to use the construction "instalments of + TIME" with the word *instalment* to express the 'length' of the instalment?

For instance, can I say

> Payment may be paid in instalments of no less than a month each

to express that the time elapsing between payments must be no less than a month?

If I can't say this, do you have any suggestions for alternative solutions?

Thank you!

Edit: I realise that the situation I'm assuming here may not be too common (although it does exist; my example is authentic, only it's in a different language), but that's not what I'm asking about – I'm only asking whether the sentence is correct from a language point of view, and whether it expresses the meaning 'instalments occurring once a month or less often'. :)

Comment: In my country, usually, repayment or instalment-purchase plans do not offer the option of varying the interval between payments, e.g. "The sum loaned is to be repaid in 36 monthly repayments".

Comment: *Payment may be paid in instalments **no less than monthly*** (or *...in no less than monthly instalments*). Though as @MichaelHarvey points out, most Western companies wouldn't offer the option of anything other than *Payment may be paid in **monthly** instalments*. But most computerised ledgers should be quite capable of recording any additional "interim"  weekly payments correctly anyway, so in practice that option might be available even if not *explicitly* mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, but please see the addition I've made to my initial question! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wouldn't "no less than monthly" mean that there must be _no more_ than a month between instalments though? Also: please see the addition I've made to my initial question :)

Comment: I wrote 'claims should be submitted at intervals no less frequent than monthly' when drafting my organisation's policy on expenses claiming.  Otherwise people leave them until year-end or when they get around to it, which we don't like.

Comment: Yes, of course it means that there must be no more than a month between instalments. No company is going to offer "easy payment" terms where the customer gets to choose arbitrarily long periods between repayments (people would just choose to make one payment every *century!* :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks again; thing is, it's the other way around in my situation :) The requirement is that it should be monthly or LESS OFTEN. Anyway, are you saying that my example sentence is incorrect FROM A LANGUAGE POINT OF VIEW – that's really all I need to know :) (Sorry for shouting; I don't know how to make sth bold in comments...)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, like I say in my edit, I realise the situation I'm after here may be uncommon, but that's really besides the point (it IS a very real situation, I can assure you :) ). What I need to know is whether my example sentence is correct from a LANGUAGE POINT OF VIEW – that is, is it grammatically correct, and does it mean what I need it to mean? (And I don't mean to shout; I just don't know how to make sth bold in comments)

Comment: @Helen to make something **bold** in a comment or answer, type two asterisks immediately before and after the text. Click 'Help' to the right of the box when making a comment to see a summary of the most common codes. Also there is a 'learn more about formatting' link.

Comment: I personally don't like your *...in instalments of no less than a month each*. Not least because if we discard the optional "no less than" constraint, we're left with ***instalments of a month each***, which I would say is syntactic nonsense (it's certainly a non-starter compared to ***monthly instalments***). Note hat precisely *because* your intended meaning is so "unusual", it's not a good idea to express it using unfamiliar / potentially suspect phrasing. I suggest you use *many* more words, to make your meaning crystal clear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **Thank you** – this is exactly the kind of help I needed :) I'll just go back to the drafting board then... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express the idea of longer or shorter intervals between repeated events, we can say no less (or no more) often (or frequent) than some time indicator thus no less often than monthly, no more frequent than quarterly.

Comment: So, would you say that "Payment may be paid in instalments no more often than monthly" would work? From a strict language point of view, that is.

Comment: It would work from a language point of view, but does it mean what you want it to mean? You're saying every three weeks is bad, every five weeks is OK. I don't know why anyone would want to do this; it sounds like a lot of trouble.

Comment: Yes – that's exactly what I mean to say :) Or rather: that's what the person I'm translating for wants to say. And who am I to question him?  :) Thank you so much for your patience and excellent help!